# Цикл for .. of проблема

Tags: javascript, html

У нас есть массив объектов newData(длина массива 9 ел.).Прохожу по нему циклом for...0f,на каждой итерации должна создаваться разметка html и вставляться в сам html.В итоге я получаю только 1 вставку этой разметки , то есть итерацию мы делаем 9 раз , а replaceItemTemplate ( разметка html ) создается только 1 раз!В чем проблема?

```js
for(item of newData) {
    var replaceItemTemplate = '<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">\
      <img src="$url" alt="$name" class="img-thumbnail">\
      <div class="info-wrapper">\
      <div class="text-muted">$name</div>\
      <div class="text-muted top-padding">$description</div>\
      <div class="text-muted">$date</div>\
      </div>\
    </div>';
    
    let resultHTML = replaceItemTemplate
     .replace(/\$name/gi, item.name)
     .replace("$url", item.url)
     .replace("$description", item.description)
     .replace("$date", item.date);

    firstBlock.innerHTML = resultHTML;
}
```

Comment: Это точно js?(2 символа)

Comment: Да , сейчас я перепишу код немного!

Comment: Ну так Вы же не добавляете разметку, а на каждой итерации её заменяете... не?

Comment: Добавляйте вёрстку, а не перезаписывайте: `firstBlock.innerHTML += resultHTML;`

Comment: То есть мне нужно исп. не innerHTML , а appendChild()?

Comment: Akina и Regent  вы абсолютно правы !Спасибо!

Comment: @Regent, `firstBlock.innerHTML += resultHTML;` будет при Каждом вызове Создавать Все элементы заново

Comment: @qwabra при длине массива в 9 элементов это не станет трагедией года. Но я не спорю, что вариант из ответа ThisMan производительнее варианта из моего комментария, плюс при повторном вызове цикла не приведёт к появлению 18 блоков

Comment: @Regent, картинки будут перезагружаться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вместо

```
firstBlock.innerHTML = resultHTML;
```

используй

```
firstBlock.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', resultHTML);
```

---

```
for(item of newData) {
    var replaceItemTemplate = '<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">\
      <img src="$url" alt="$name" class="img-thumbnail">\
      <div class="info-wrapper">\
      <div class="text-muted">$name</div>\
      <div class="text-muted top-padding">$description</div>\
      <div class="text-muted">$date</div>\
      </div>\
    </div>';

    let resultHTML = replaceItemTemplate
     .replace(/\$name/gi, item.name)
     .replace("$url", item.url)
     .replace("$description", item.description)
     .replace("$date", item.date);

    firstBlock.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', resultHTML);
}
```

---

и вообще

```
let resultHTML = `
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
          <img src="${item.url}" alt="${item.name}" class="img-thumbnail">
          <div class="info-wrapper">
          <div class="text-muted">${item.name}</div>
          <div class="text-muted top-padding">${item.description}</div>
          <div class="text-muted">${item.date}</div>
          </div>
</div>
`
```

Answer (score 2):

`innerHTML` полностью переписывает содержимое, то есть вы каждый раз переписываете содержимое, в итоге после цикла у вас останется только последний вариант

```
let resultHTML = ''
for(item of newData) {
    var replaceItemTemplate = '<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">\
      <img src="$url" alt="$name" class="img-thumbnail">\
      <div class="info-wrapper">\
      <div class="text-muted">$name</div>\
      <div class="text-muted top-padding">$description</div>\
      <div class="text-muted">$date</div>\
      </div>\
    </div>';


    // добавляем к результату на каждой иттерации
    htmlResult += replaceItemTemplate
     .replace(/\$name/gi, item.name)
     .replace("$url", item.url)
     .replace("$description", item.description)
     .replace("$date", item.date);
}

firstBlock.innerHTML = resultHTML;
```